# Scikitlearn GridSearchCV best model scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to print the training and test score of the best model from my `GridSearchCV` object. My initial guess was  to use `cv_results['best_train_score']` and `cv_results['best_test_score']`  but after looking at the documentation I dont think there is a 'best_train_score' for cv_results.

I also see that there is a `best_estimator_` but I'm not sure if I can use this to print a test and a training score. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `best_estimator_` of your fitted `GridSearchCV` to retrieve the best model and then use the `score` function of your estimator to calculate the train and test accuracy.

As follows:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.2
)

parameters = {"kernel": ("linear", "rbf"), "C": [1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC()
cv = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)
cv.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
model = cv.best_estimator_

print(f"train score: {model.score(X_train, y_train)}")
print(f"test score: {model.score(X_test, y_test)}")
```

Output:

```
train score: 0.9916666666666667
test score: 1.0
```